# preg_replace (and other) causing resulting Javascript problems on Windows

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am stuck with a weird problem. I've never seen anything like that before and I can't find any similar cases to my problem. I am on Windows 7, PHP 5.5.x and Apache.

My framework is serving javascript by itself (e.g. with `readfile(...)`) . This approach allows me to translate and serve javascript files on the fly (duh!). For instance, if JS code contains smth like `var msg="<translate>This string</translate>";` then, when it's being served by the framework, `<translate>` tags are translated with

```
preg_replace_callback('/<translate>(.*?)<\/translate>/i', $callback, $content);
```

Where `$callback` is the function that translates `$content`.

The `$callback` can be boiled down to this simple code (which still will cause JS to render improperly):

```
$callback = function($matches) {
    return $matches[1];
};
```

All in all it works well on Linux, but when I try running that on Windows, my Firefox refuses to interpret translated JS code!

Has anyone had any similar problems?

I've also tried `preg_replace`, `preg_replace_callback` and even `str_replace` just for fun. Any string replacement in JS code leads to errors on client side. Explicitly setting `charset=utf-8` in `Content-Type` header doesnt help either.

Comment: Can you show us the translated output?

Comment: @dman2306 The translated output for the example that I gave in my post would be `var msg="This string"`. I'll add a `$callback` to the initial post so you can see what's happening.

Comment: That'd be great. I was asking because obviously if your translation inserted " you might have issues. Also when you say there are errors on the client side, could you share the error message you receive? Also is it only Firefox or other browsers as well?

Comment: I've tried on Chrome... Apart from JS error messages I found that Chrome threw another error right before saying `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. The JS errors are simply saying smth like `ReferenceError: $ns is not defined`, where `$ns` is my namespace object. Any ideas? Btw, the `$callback` function is added to the post. Please take a look

Comment: I don't know how much HTML your code renders, but seeing the output in full (from view source) would probably be helpful since that seems to be where the error lies. Meaning you're providing an example of `var msg` however you gave an error of `$ns`. I don't see a `$ns` in your question anywhere. It's kind of hard to debug an error when you're showing different code than the error refers to.

Comment: Sorry for long delay. I cannot post the original code, so I stripped it down to the basic of basics. Included in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/andreyvk/b621426fd0009cd66856) is the 
1. PHP code that includes javascript. `includeJs()` basically creates `<script>` tags which has a `src` pointed to the `main.js` file
2. That url calls framework to read JS file and translate it as I described in the original post
3. The output of JS file is also shown in the same gist.

I am very lost now :)

Comment: PS - sorry for not being able to order the sequence in GIST. Here's how to  the sequence runs: **1**. php_code_that_calls_js_include; **2**. framework_generated_html; **3**. main.js; **4**.  translated-main.js

Answer (score 0):

I've realized it right after I stripped down everything and saw a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` message once again in Chrome. The problem was is that **I was sending a `Content-Length` header (length was set to the `filesize($file)` before I translated my JS files**. Hence the problem.

I am not sure why it works in Linux with (more or less) default settings for Apache, but it does not work well with Windows' Apache.

@dman2306 Thank you for the input!